# Nginx multiple DNS to same webserver

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

## GOAL https://imgur.com/a/A04qrXz

#### ^ Trying to get multiple (different) domains pointing at the same IP, serving the same files to bypass DNS filtering agent GoGaurdian.

Webserver SRC : https://github.com/Zaydo123/html-game-server

Why: trying to bypass a DNS filtering service

My /etc/nginx/conf.d/physics.conf (works fine)

```
server {

    server_name physics-central.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/physics-central.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/physics-central.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = physics-central.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen *:80 default_server;
    listen 8000 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name physics-central.com;
    return 301 https://physics-central.com$request_uri; # managed by Certbot

}
```

## Problem

From my little knowledge of Nginx, I assume I need to create one .conf file for each domain. Each is essentially the same but has different SSL certs and domain names. I tried doing this but upon reloading I received this warning/error.

`nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/physics.conf:27`

### My question

Am I going about this wrong? Am I supposed to even be making conf.d files for each domain? It would be amazing if you could help me out. Thanks.

Comment: remove all those lines indicating `default_server`. You can only have one file containing that since that will serve all request except for request that are handled by server_name

Comment: You have to have a server block for each of the domain simply because you need them to serve different ssl certificates